# Open a LWC on Salesforce Mobile app via Mobile URL Schemes

Tags: salesforce, url-scheme, lwc

I need to open a LWC on the Salesforce Mobile app via Mobile URL Schemes, but the link always redirect the user to the app home page

I have read the Mobile URL Schemes documentation, but I didn't find a way to open an LWC; only objects with specific operations. Is there a way to redirect the user to an LWC via this kind of URL?